# Intellisense error with _com_ptr_t since Visual Studio 2017 15.5.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, intellisense, atl

I have a `_com_ptr_t` instantiation generated from importing a .tlb file which is used in the following...

```
#import "object.tlb"

void demo()
{
    IObjectPtr p;
    p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Object));
    p->DoSomething();
}
```

Prior to VS2017 15.5.1 this code was parsed by Intellisense correctly and built fine. Now, in 15.5.1 and beyond, I get the squiggles under both `CreateInstance` and `p` when `p->DoSomething()`, as show below with the Intellisense tooltips notated as comments.

```
#import "object.tlb"

void demo()
{
    IObjectPtr p;

    // class "_com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<IObject, &__uuidof(IObject)>>" 
    // has no member "CreateInstance"
    p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Object));

    // expression must have a pointer type.
    p->DoSomething();
}
```

Interestingly, when I dot into the object, Intellisense only shows one available member, `GetIID`, but the code builds and runs without issue.

I've tried ignoring the squiggles, but I use A LOT of com calls in my code and it's exceedingly difficult to sift the real errors out from the pile of phony errors. I've tried clean and rebuild. I've tried deleting the .vs directory. I've tried clearing the component cache. Nothing has worked. What gives?

Comment: They need a better bug report than [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/218827/vc-%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E6%AD%A3%E7%A1%AE%E6%8F%90%E7%A4%BA%E6%99%BA%E8%83%BD%E6%8C%87%E9%92%88%E5%AF%B9%E8%B1%A1.html).  File it with Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: This is a chronic problem for me too.

Comment: I've filled out a bug report with Microsoft. I'll keep us updated here as they respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
Looks like the problem has been fixed in 15.8 update for VS.

*Old answer*
We've faced a similar problem in our projects.
I've noticed that it only shows up when we switch to C++17 language standard. Turning back to c++14 makes Intellisense behave properly.